# Angular-translate: how to translate Ionic directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-translate, ionic-view

**THE QUESTION:**

I am translating my Ionic app into several languages. I am using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) that does a very good job.

However there are some compatibility issues using it with Ionic directives such as ion-view

**EXAMPLE:**

In these ways is working smoothly:

```
<h4> { 'EDIT_YOUR_INFO' | translate } </h4>
```

simple usage as filter

```
<p ng-bind-html=" 'USERNAME' | translate "></p>
```

using ng-bind to avoid issues with foreign characters

**THE ISSUE:**

`<h4>` and `<p>` are HTML tags and there are no problem at all using angular-translate with them. Everything is working fine.

The problems are when have to translate Ionic directive, such as `<ion-view>`

```
<ion-view view-title="Edit Profile">
```

The words 'Edit Profile' will appear in the upper header bar. I need to translate also them. I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
<ion-view view-title="'PROFILE_EDIT' | translate">
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i translate Ionic directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `{{ }}` for expressions on normal attributes.

```
<ion-view view-title="{{ 'PROFILE_EDIT' | translate }}">
```

Comment: This does not work for me when I click on an link to get to the page on which I want to translate an ion-view view-title. Where is the problem?

Comment: @MHDaouas Please ask a new question with your specific situation.